# Apply CSS rule except when element is nested using :not

Tags: html, css

So I have:

```
.element {
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: block;
}
```

but I'd like this rule to be ignored when `.element` is a child of `.no-border` using the `:not` pseudo-selector. Example:

```
<div class="element">I have a border</div>

<div class="no-border">
   <div class="element">I don't have a border</div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to do this using the following:

```
:not(.no-border) .element {
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: block;
}
```

However, the border is still applying to `.element` if it is a child of `.no-border`.

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lox10pL/1/

Any help?

Comment: If it is always a direct child, use `:not(.no-border) > .element`. The current one doesn't work because the `body` doesn't have `no-border` class and that also is an ancestor of `.element`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use direct descendent selector `>`:

```
:not(.no-border)>.element
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lox10pL/4/)

Comment: Great, thanks. But what happens if it's not a direct descendent?

Comment: @user2726041 Then you can use my answer :)

Comment: @user2726041: then, I guess, you should change the logic, for example, apply class directly to the item.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLam and potashin but unfortunately the real site I am working on doesn't allow me to edit the HTML and the rule-set applied to the element I am trying to ignore is very complex

Comment: This is a very interesting solution @potashin. Can you explain why this works this way? I mean, :not(.no-border) would be any element that doesn't have .no-border as a class...and then all inner children that have class element within those .. thats where it should be applied. I'm just curious on why the original rule wouldn't work...its driving me bonkers not knowing :)

Comment: @Carine: because there are outer elements that don't have `no-border` class, thus the rule is always applied

Comment: @potashin Yes I understand that, however this isn't just looking for ":not(.no-border)"   its looking for .element that is within :not(.no-border) .....wait..unless because its a jsfiddle, it (the first .element) is already wrapped in something else....aha..i think thats it...am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate selector whenever it is a child of `.no-border` and override the styles with `initial`, e.g.,:

```
.no-border .element {
   border: initial;
   display: initial;
}
```

See the fiddle at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lox10pL/5/).

Comment: This is the correct answer for what the user is looking for, there's no need to use :not pseudo selector to solve this. If you have a lot of rules you just need to apply initial to all of them. If you're not sure what are the css properties being applied to the element, use dev tools and find out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
.outerclass {
        h3 {
            color: blue;
        }
        :not(.nested) (div > div)
        {
            color: green;
        }
        }
```